# Debugging Error while translating phrase “%s” in file %s. in Magento 2.3.5-P1

Tags: magento2, json

I'm currently building a site with Magento 2.3.5-P1 (installed via composer) I've added a theme (Porto) and a small number of 3rd party extensions

I've just noticed that on the product pages there is an error in the console and nothing works (no links are clickable, add to cart not working, attributes missing, additional images missing etc) The console error is:

https://xxx.co.uk/pub/static/version1602316619/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/js-translation.json HTTP status: 404

When running the command bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f I see the following error:

Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s.

I presume the 2 are related but I have no idea how to start debugging this? I've tried deactivating the 3rd party extensions but the error is still there? Magento doesn't log anything to even start looking into any code etc...?

Comment: The 404 suggests that this file either was missing from the Porto theme files, failed to copy during the static file deployment, or exists on the file system but cannot be seen by the webserver. Be aware that once static files start failing to load, a lot of things can go haywire and create confusing failure states. A browser's dev tool network tab will show if this is the only 404, or just the first domino to fall. Switching to developer mode might help unearth some more helpful logging. You can also sometimes see errors logged in the HTML source, and of course the web server's error log.

Comment: Would you say it's a Porto issue? I've been in touch with the Porto dev's and they are claiming it's not the theme (as theme dev's do)

So far I've uploaded fresh magento files, uploaded fresh Porto files + disabled all 3rd party extensions and I still get the "Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s." error when deploying and the same error on the frontend... It's frustrating as Magento doesn't report which string it cannot translate...

Comment: Hard to say, but *probably* not. I'm sure the dev's perspective is "100 people installed this theme yesterday, and nobody else is having this issue." (As far as they know.) It seems unlikely that a missing JSON file would cause such a cascade of problems. This makes me suspect that there is a larger issue of frontend files either not deploying to pub/static or not loading. There could also be a bug that is breaking the require.js dependencies, but I would start by ensuring that widespread 404s are not the issue.

Comment: Thanks, the only 2 404 errors I get are the following:

js-translation.json and 

https://www.xxx.uk/new2020/pub/static/version1602434160/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/Magento_Theme/

Comment: The second link, pub/static/version1602434160/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/Magento_Theme/, is returning a 404? As a directory, it seems like that shouldn't be possible. If the directory contents aren't loading that would certainly cause problems. It's hard to know exactly what it should contain, since this is a function of Porto, Magento and every other extension that may be adding/overriding the JS/CSS/HTML files. One thing that might be worth a try, is changing the locale setting. A bug specific to a locale is slightly more likely to slip through the cracks.

Comment: I'm starting to think I am going to have to bin a weeks work and start the whole site again, I've completely removed Porto and it's extensions plus disabled all other 3rd party extensions, changed the locale back to en_US and I still get the error deploying static content - I've even updated Magento to 2.3.5-P2 but still no joy... It's really annoying that Magento doesn't have any logging for translation errors

Comment: Just an update... I am now thinking this maybe server / hosting related.... I've installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.3.5-p2 in a sub directory and without even touching anything I am getting the js-translation.json 404 error on the frontend and deploying static content gives the "Error while translating phrase "%s" in file %s" error????